# TimeOut calling WebServices with Axis 2/JBoss Ws

Tags: java, web-services, cxf, apache-axis, jboss6.x

I have a problem calling a Webservice with Axis2. I have done in cxf without any problem, so i know that the service is responding. But, because of problems with the compatibility between Jboss 6 and CXF, i need to do in another tech. (I am trying to migrate to Jboss 7, where there isnt any problem, but boss don't want at this moment).

So, the request in cxf is going perfect. When i try in Axis2 doesn't work. I suppose that i am not doing something good, some configuration that cxf do itself and no Axis2.

I have this error in axis2:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:170)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:465)
at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:503)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:973)
at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:930)
at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:105)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:246)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:265)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readRawLine(HttpParser.java:78)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpParser.readLine(HttpParser.java:106)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpConnection.readLine(HttpConnection.java:1116)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$HttpConnectionAdapter.readLine(MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager.java:1413)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readStatusLine(HttpMethodBase.java:1973)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.readResponse(HttpMethodBase.java:1735)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodBase.execute(HttpMethodBase.java:1098)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeWithRetry(HttpMethodDirector.java:398)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethodDirector.executeMethod(HttpMethodDirector.java:171)
at org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient.executeMethod(HttpClient.java:397)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AbstractHTTPSender.executeMethod(AbstractHTTPSender.java:621)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender.sendViaPost(HTTPSender.java:193)
```

In the project that works, made in cxf, if i change the call, putting with the Jboss6 runtime and remove the cxf library (2.7.18), with the same code, i get this error:

```
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:422)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:460)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:820)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:75)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:698)
at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:641)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1218)
at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:379)
at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:318)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponseInternal(HTTPConduit.java:2223)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.handleResponse(HTTPConduit.java:2192)
at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.HTTPConduit$WrappedOutputStream.close(HTTPConduit.java:2036)
... 12 more
```

Very similar.

In axis 2 i try changing the protocol to 1.0, but the error persist.

```
org.tempuri.RldServiceStub stub = new org.tempuri.RldServiceStub();
    org.tempuri.RldServiceStub.InsertarDocumento insertarDocumento40 = (org.tempuri.RldServiceStub.InsertarDocumento) getTestObject(org.tempuri.RldServiceStub.InsertarDocumento.class);

    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setUserName("b3e4af71-ff47-4451-88d5-1afcf9fb0412");
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setPassword("CcVAx5yxL5fC80bw7SAQBMTfXWvEp1YI/sO2YYyJQm4=");
    stub._getServiceClient().getOptions().setProperty(org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HTTP_PROTOCOL_VERSION, org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPConstants.HEADER_PROTOCOL_10);
```

I am too lost in this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You have to know that Apache Axis is not supported as a Web Service Stack on JBoss EAP. It is recommended to use the WS implementation bundled with your current JBoss EAP. To be specific, for JBoss EAP 6 is JBossWS Apache CXF.